# Sandbox Digital Experience- Page not available

Tags: community, partner-communities, digital-experience

I'm building a partner experience in sandbox and I keep randomly getting a "Page not available" errors when I try to go to a record detail page. If I log out and log back in and try to go to the same record it works but then randomly the same record will stop working and I will get the error.

I noticed that the URLs look confused. The user was trying to go and get a work order but when he clicked it he got a url structured as: /s/bid/Bid_c/Defaultdetail/salesforceID.
[image: Error image]

In the one that works the url is structured as: /s/workorder/salesforceID
Both have the same record IDs.

[image: No error]

So it appears that something is causing part of the url to change object types from work order to bid and adding the defaultdetail part into the URL.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I did some more digging and I noticed that the URLs look confused. The user was trying to go and get a work order but when he clicked it he got a url structured like:When the user tried the url showed /s/